# SKCropNode precision problems

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture, skcropnode

I am developing a game in which I require several images to be overlaid in order to allow the player to choose the colour of their plane. I do this using the following code:

```
SKCropNode *cropper = [SKCropNode node];

SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:planeImageName];

SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Camo"];

SKSpriteNode *paint = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];

SKSpriteNode *outline = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:planeOutlineImageName];
outline.size = CGSizeMake(mask.size.width, mask.size.height);


LRHeroPlane *hero = [LRHeroPlane spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];

[hero addChild:cropper];
[cropper addChild:paint];
[cropper setMaskNode:mask];
[hero addChild:outline];
```

Where `planeOutlineImageName` and `planeImageName` are strings which can be used to find the images in my asset catalogue, and `hero` is the root node. When I add this to my scene, however, the camouflage paint goes beyond the borders of the outline, leaving the full plane looking messy and unprofessional. Below are the images used: (The actual images are .pdf but I converted them to .png to include them in this post)

[image: Picture with name <code>planeImageName</code>]
[image: Camo paint]
[image: Picture with name <code>planeOutlineImageName</code>] 
[image: resulting plane]

Does anybody know why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My guess is because you are using PDF, and the scaling is causing antialiasing, meaning your border has an alpha > 0.5

Comment: so I need to use a bitmap file format?

Comment: I would recommend it,  the only thing the pdf does is makes the png files for you at runtime, you do not save space by using it

Comment: Any suggestions as to what resolution I should make these to match the auto-made ones? (i.e. what size are the @1 @2 and @3 sizes).

Comment: Whatever size your asset is in the game is 1x,  2x and 3x are just double and triple that size

Comment: But my asset is in .pdf format - do these have sizes too?

Comment: Pdf is weird, it is technically a scalable graphic(may even be vector) so I have no idea what the size is.  Go into the asset in Xcode, it should tell you

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I will upload an answer once I have checked if it works.